# How to get the details of memory space used by a process in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, process

How can I know the details of the physical addresses used by a process?

My task is to check for bad parts in memory that may have resulted in crashing an application. So, I've to get all the physical addresses used by the application so that I can run a memory test on that memory space.

I know processes use virtual addresses, so, is there a way to get all the virtual addresses and lock the memory space to run a memory test on it? (I mean, I don't want to let other processes use the memory space that's been used by my application till I run a memory test on it.)

(By the way, It's a C++ program and I'll run the memory test in exception handler, so I'll have access to virtual address space of the process.)

Comment: You can't, unless using a kernel mode driver. And, you do not need them. Every memory address at the application level, including exceptions, is virtual. Even if you could, I don't see how a "memory test" on the physical memory would help.

Comment: Why not just run something like `memtest` to test the ram?

Comment: You mean like CheatEngine does? You can find many coding examples by googling "C++ memory scanner" (I guess most of them are game hacking sites). I don't know exactly what you mean with "locking the memory", but you could suspend the process to hinder alternation of memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't want to test the entire RAM. I have to test the memory space used by my application.

Comment: @JulianH I meant, I don't want to let other processes use the memory space that's been used by my application till I run a memory test on it.

Comment: You can try [VMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap).